# Future cancel not working with executorService for multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying write an api to stop multiple threads with java executorService and Future.

Below is my code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/work")
public class WorkController {

    final WorkService service;
    private List<Future<?>> future_list;

    public WorkController(WorkService service) {
        this.service = service;
        this.future_list = null;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/start",
            method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes="application/json")

    public String startWorks(@RequestBody List<Long> workIds) throws IOException {

        // create runnables based on work ids
        int work_number = workIds.size();
        Collection<Runnable> worker_list= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < work_number; i++) {
            Runnable worker = service.createWorkRunnable(workIds.get(i));
            worker_list.add(worker);
        }

        // 4 thread pool
        ExecutorService executor;
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

        for (Runnable worker : worker_list) {
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(worker);
            future_list.add(future);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

        return "Finished all threads";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/stop",
            method=RequestMethod.POST)

    public String stopWorks() {
        for (Future<?> f : future_list) {
            Boolean paused = f.cancel(true);
        }
        return "Stoped";
    }

}
```

When I called stopWorks while runnables are executing, I get

```
[ERROR] 2018-08-21 06:46:05.275 [http-nio-8090-exec-5] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Re
quest processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

It seems that the future is not assigned. Am I on the right track to try interrupt on multiple threads. If so, what did I do wrongly? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you don't initialize `future_list` in the constructor. Further, it is better to inject the `ExecutorService`. I have reworked the code a bit to also use other best practises:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/work")
public class WorkController {

    private final WorkService service;
    private final ExecutorService executor;
    private List<Future<?>> futureList;

    public WorkController(WorkService service, ExecutorService executor) {
        this.service = service;
        this.executor = executor;
        this.futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/start", consumes = "application/json")
    public String startWorks(@RequestBody List<Long> workIds) {
        // create runnables based on work ids
        Collection<Runnable> workerList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Long workId : workIds) {
            Runnable worker = service.createWorkRunnable(workId);
            workerList.add(worker);
        }

        for (Runnable worker : workerList) {
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(worker);
            futureList.add(future);
        }

        return "Finished all threads";
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop")
    public String stopWorks() {
        for (Future<?> f : futureList) {
            f.cancel(true);
        }
        return "Stopped";
    }
}
```

To have an `ExecutorService` for injection, create a bean like this:

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService executorService() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
}
```

Note that are still issues even with this code:

- The `futureList` is never cleaned up, so it will grow without bounds. Handling this correctly is not as easy as it seems as there are multiple threads involved (`startWorks` can be called multiple times, also `stopWorks`)
- Should it be allowed to call `startWorks` multiple times if there is already work busy?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will look at these issues! Still trying to get this work first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you did not initiate `future_list`:

```
public WorkController(WorkService service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.future_list = null; // assign it a List instead null
}
```